# C++ Inline Operator Overloading, refer to current object

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading, swap, assignment-operator

So I only recently started using "Inline operator overloading" or whatever it's called......
Anyways!! How can I refer to the object I am calling the function from. Here's the code of interest:

```
class PlayingCard
{
private:
    enum Suit {diamond, hearts, spades, clubs};
    Suit suit;
    enum Color {red, black};
    Color color;
    int value = -1;
public:
    //Inline stuff

    //make card the same as c1
    inline operator=(const PlayingCard &c1) {
        suit = c1.suit;
        color = c1.color;
        value = c1.value;
        return true;
    }

    inline operator%(PlayingCard &c1) {
        PlayingCard copy1;
        copy1 = c1;
        c1 = this;
        this = copy1;
        return true;
    }
```

As you can see I have the class PlayingCard. The first inline operator works just as it should. If I have 2 PlayingCard: c1 and c2 with the private values of c2 being defined then c1 = c2 makes the private values of c1 equal to c2.

The second inline function is meant to swap the values between c1 and c2 by doing c1 % c2. As is shown in the code I was hoping to use "this" to refer to c1 but it doesn't work. Is there a way to refer to c1 in this function?

I know there are work-arounds which I'll be using in the meantime, but I'd rather use my original method and I feel like it would be helpful for future use as well.

Comment: There is no such things as a `<->` operator in C++.

Comment: You mean using `this` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such an operator as `<->` (that you later changed to `%` in the updated question) in C++. It seems you want to define a member function `swap`. But in any case you may not swap constant objects. So the parameter of the function should be a non-constant reference.

Member functions defined in class definitions by default have the function specifier inline. So there is no need to explicitly specify it.

The assignment operator should return a reference to the assigned object.

Here you are.

```
PlayingCard & operator =( const PlayingCard &c1 ) 
{
    if ( this != &c1 )
    {
        suit  = c1.suit;
        color = c1.color;
        value = c1.value;
    }

    return *this;
}

void swap( PlayingCard &c1 ) 
{
    if ( this != &c1 )
    {
        std::swap( suit, c1.suit );
        std::swap( color, c1.color );
        std::swap( value, c1.value );
    }
}
```

Comment: Haha, yeah I noticed I couldn't use the <-> after doing the work-arounds. The swap function will definitely be helpful. Is there a way to refer to the object itself as I was trying? Whether I use it here or not I feel like it could be helpful to know.
Thanks for the quick answers!

Comment: @DerekMuller I am sorry, I have not understood your question. Do you mean the pointer this?

Comment: @DerekMuller You can use the pointer this in the swap function provided that the class has either copy or move constructor.

Comment: Umm... if I were to not switch to the void swap function and kept it as it's own operator (now % instead of <-> )  Is there a way to use the '=' operator already defined to swap the values in the function for % and referring to the current PlayingCard, defining a separate temporary PlayingCard as a middle man. So card % c1 would reference the function in the class written as : operator%(const PlayingCard c1){PlayingCard temp; temp = c1; c1 = <refer to card>; <refer to card> = temp; return;}
Is there any way to do the <refer to card> part?

Comment: @DerekMuller Using an operator instead of the function name swap will confuse readers of the code.  As I already wrote in a comment you can use an intermediate object of the class in the swap function to swap the object *this with the object passed as an argument.

Comment: @DerekMuller For example the function can look like  void swap( A &a )
 {
  A tmp( std::move( a ) );
  a = std::move( *this );
  *this = std::move( tmp );
 }
 where A is some class.

Answer (score 0):

Operator overloading in C++ only allows you to do certain ones that the language provides. You don't get to make up your own. So you can't make one for `<->`

(There may be some convoluted way to assemble something out of the individual `<`, `-`, and `>` operators. But even if that's possible, it probably wouldn't be worth the effort and would most likely allow unintended weird usages as well.)